# Tags feed in GitLab shows only 20 entries

Tags: gitlab, atom-feed

I need to find a way to get all release names and release dates for a project in GitLab.
I tried retrieving Tags feed, but it seems to contain only 20 entries-so the older tags are not in the feeds.

How can i easily get those Release information for a project / Group.
I couldn't download Release_evidence JSON for each release. That's not a problem.
But I need an easy way to get all those release information.

> <project>/-/tags?format=atom

only displays 20 entries.How to get all entries regarding release information easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitLab documentation helped me in this case to retrieve all feeds

This link ---> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination

Scanning through the available pages using "***page=n***" query parameter in the URL and read the feed entries from each page until there are no feed entries helped me.

> <project>/-/tags?format=atom&page=n, where n=1,2,3...

*'per_page'* query parameter didn't work for me. but the *'page'* query parameter helped me

Hope it helps someone